# Elasticsearch nested type has risks?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested-types

I want to use nested type instead of object type for arrays in order to get the expected search result (as explained in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html).
My array may contain big amount of elements and. As I understood, each element will be stored in its own document.
What are the risks of using nested type?

Comment: Can you define "big amount"?

Comment: sometimes more than 1K...

Comment: You might be better off denormalizing your documents but hard to say for sure without knowing your use case in more details.